# Are molecular properties robust towards manipulations?

Tags: cheminformatics, machine-learning

Machine learning algorithms analyze molecules by looking at their molecular representations (e. g. SMILES and graph) and turning them into feature maps that help the algorithm to distinguish them. In the case of graph representations, algorithm tends to generate similar feature maps for the molecules that have similar topologies.

I was wondering if it is a correct assumption, generally speaking, that molecules with similar molecular graphs tend to have similar properties. That is, if we slightly modify one molecule, the output is expected to be close to the original molecule.

---

EDITS:

It seems this assumption is the base for [Chemical Similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_similarity). It goes on to say

> [...] descriptive network properties and graph theory can be applied
> to analyze large chemical space

At the end of the day, I think it is true that it all depends on what type of properties I'm dealing with. But my understanding is that this chemical similarity provides a base for more complex problems to build upon. For instance, if I want to modify a particular property, I would just add that into my initial analysis of the molecule.

Comment: Depends on the feature, I guess. A small modification will not change molecular mass by much, for example; on the other hand, it may turn an aldehyde to an acid.

Comment: It would be good to have an idea of what "slightly" could signify in this context? For instance are Benzene and Dewar Benzene only slightly different? If so one is a stable molecule known for centuries, the other wasn't synthesised until 1962 and has half life of around 2 days.

Comment: Adding a substituent, is it a small change ?

Comment: Another example is benzene vs toluene. Substituting an H with a CH3 might be a change for a graph or symmetry, but surely is not for a graph or symmetry as seen by pi electrons. Or one is a powerful carcinogen, the other seems to be safe. This can be and is done having the features in mind; topology and symmetry lead to rules, even. But the graph must be have something in common. Otherwise all biatomic molecules would have the almost the same properties, while in reality the only thing they share is x-x

Comment: When neither the algorithm nor the user have the slightest idea what they're doing ... ;-)

Comment: Even minor structural rearrangements can have big effects, eg n-butanol has a melting point of approx. negative 90 C, while its isomer t-butanol has an mp of positive 25 C. Both are aliphatic alcohols of formula $\ce{C4H10O}$.

Comment: @Karl When people have nothing to offer but still comment . . .

Comment: Neither classical chemometrics nor ML does require perfect connection between the similar molecules. Finding good descriptors is the job itself. If you find good ones, then you have found good ones...

Comment: Can you clarify the question? It is not clear what are asking or missing. The assumption that structure is somehow relevant to properties is about the same as saying chemical properties are related to chemical structure somehow, most of the time. I.e. that Chemistry kind of works. Since you are using these terms rather loosely, my statement seems more strict. You yourself acknowledge that the given assumption tends to work. What is the question?

Comment: @Greg While changing one atom or one bond in a molecule can drastically change the properties of a molecule, machine learning algorithms represent them with similar representations. Essentially, if we manipulate a molecule just a little bit, the ML representation would also change a little bit. So is this justified? Are molecular properties robust towards manipulations? It seems that the concept of chemical similarity is built upon robustness towards manipulations. But how can I justify drastic changes that we may see by just changing one atom or one bond or changing order of a bond.

Comment: @Blade It depends on the descriptor and metrics what is a small change. If you intentionally choose bad metrics, then of course they will not work. Chemometrics has collected literally hundreds of similarity measures that can work in a given context, the devil is in the details. I only can repeat: ML algorithms are universal approximators, ergo all you are asking here is that "is there any relationship between structure and property?", in short: "does chemistry make any sense?".